# C# gets 500 error, VB does not?

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpwebresponse

I've been racking my brain on this one and can't come up with a good reason why, but when I run my vb.net code, it executes fine.  I was reworking it into c# (learning process) and I get a 'server returned 500' error at the `GetResponse` line.

Any advice is appreciated greatly!

C# code - broken

```
string SpaceURL = "https://1.1.1.1/api/space/device-management/discover-devices";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SpaceURL);
        request.ContentType = "application/vnd.net.juniper.space.device-management.discover-devices+xml;version=1;charset=UTF-8";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic authcode");
        request.Method = "POST";

        //Get the request text for stream writer
        CommonFunctions objCF = new CommonFunctions();
        string strRequest = objCF.SerializeObject(this,true,false);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(strRequest);

        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

VB.net code below works fine

```
Dim url As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    url = "https://1.1.1.1/api/space/device-management/discover-devices"
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.ContentType = "application/vnd.net.juniper.space.device-management.discover-devices+xml;version=1;charset=UTF-8"
    request.Accept = "*/*"
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic authcode=")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim requesttext As String = "<systemDiscoveryRule><ruleName>testdiscovery</ruleName><ipAddressDiscoveryTarget><ipAddress>" & txtIPAddress.Text & "</ipAddress></ipAddressDiscoveryTarget><usePing>true</usePing><useSnmp>false</useSnmp><snmpV1Setting><communityName>nsn-space</communityName></snmpV1Setting><manageDiscoveredSystemsFlag>true</manageDiscoveredSystemsFlag><sshCredential><userName>username</userName><password>password</password></sshCredential><tagNewlyManagedDiscoveredSystemsFlag>true</tagNewlyManagedDiscoveredSystemsFlag><tagForNewlyManagedDiscoveredSystems>store-devices</tagForNewlyManagedDiscoveredSystems></systemDiscoveryRule>"
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream)
    sw.Write(requesttext)
    sw.Dispose()
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

I've also compared my inline xml to the XML created in the C# version from serializing a class object (much cleaner!)

Comment: You don't flush the writer in the C# version, in the VB version you `Dispose`, which will call `Close`, which in turn calls `Flush`. The `using` statement is your friend here. Not sure if this is the issue, as the `request.Headers.Add` call also has different arguments in the two versions.

Comment: Is this **actual** code? Because there is a blatant typo in there (see also the code coloring)

Comment: The ' - " was a typo when transfering and taking out the real authcode. (which screwed up the coloring...sorry about that)

Comment: Adam, that was the fix, adding the `flush` and `dispose` corrected the issue.  Thanks a ton, not sure how I missed that line when changing to C#!

Answer (score 4):

Can you check this line

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic authcode');
```

should read

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic authcode");
```

It has mismatched quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

As  Adam Houldsworth said

> You don't flush the writer in the C# version, in the VB version you
>   `Dispose`, which will call `Close`, which in turn calls `Flush`. The
>   using statement is your friend here. Not sure if this is the issue, as
>   the request.Headers.Add call also has different arguments in the two
>   versions.